# instance object can call static method but not static variable

Tags: php, oop, static

I am trying to wrap my head around the static keyword in PHP. Here I wrote a small piece of code where my `person1` instance of `Human` can call a static method called `sayRealname()`. But when I try to call a public static variable it gives an error. What is the reason for that?

```
class Human{
    public static $age=34;
    public static $name='humpty dumpty';
    protected static $realname='al';

    public static function sayRealname(){
        echo self::$age;
    }
}

$person1=new Human();
echo $person1->name; // error
$person1->sayRealname(); // prints 34
```

Comment: Why would name be static?

Comment: it could be anything .. i call it name ..

Comment: FYI, if you just want to get it to work... `echo $person1::$name;`

Comment: ok thanks! but why i can access the static method using an arrow operator ?

Comment: Because that's not how the language is defined :)

Comment: Calling the arrow function with arrow operator will throw an E_STRICT warning in current versions of PHP as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you're accessing static content, you need to use the static operator `::`.

On the other hand, the arrow operator `->` is meant to be used in an instance context, which belongs to the particular instance upon it's being called.

You can read more about this in this part of the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.properties).